# Area of Use for webservices?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I'm used to program Desktop applications and old School (without web Services) web pages. Now after reading up on web Services and also wcf I'm unsure about the area of usage for web Services.

The Situation is so, that I have a couple hundred Clients in an external Network who try to Access the Server by sending Status Infos to it and requesting Infos from the Server and files (a few hundred MB as max. filesize, average filesize 2KB - 5MB). The Clients themselves and the Server (with the Server also interacting with a SQL database) are all Windows machines.

There is no user interaction. The Clients themselves have programs running which do all the communication with the Server automatically.

I've seen applications do These sort of things with sockets and also WCF. Still though from what I read on web Services I'm unsure if applications like this fall into their area of use or not. Thus are web Services suited for this type of Server / Client architecture?

Comment: yes, you can use them just like WCF

Comment: @ewan So also suited / equally suited for such Scenarios?

Comment: yes, although the large filesize is unusual you might want a more complex resumable stream or something

Comment: @ewan I have no Troubles Splitting the files into multiple parts of 1MB each and send them one by one (to avoid any timeout issues).

Comment: that might be wise over a certain size. Obvs depends on the network.

Answer (score 1):

there are lots of ways to do web services depending on the language and framework you want to use. WCF is how older versions of .net did web services, the more modern approach from Microsoft is WebAPI. WCF can still be used, but it has a lot more configuration overhead and makes writing clients that use the service more difficult for non .net based clients. WebAPI is designed to be very similar to MVC applications in .net and also designed to be consumed easily by anything that can make a web request. Web services is a pretty generic term, that covers tons of different frameworks and styles, and any of them are useful for connecting via the internet to send/receive data.

Web services are useful for pretty much anything that uses the internet in a client/server fashion. Since web services are built on http, or another protocol on top of http, they are very easy to make use of over the internet and don't require opening additional ports on servers. They are therefore limited to only being stateless connections, so other solutions like web sockets are needed for things that require stateful connections.